# default value 0 in foreign key field raising error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I set default value as 0 in foreign key field in Django model. But it is raising IntigrityError (1048, "Column 'country_id' cannot be null")

Hi, I have code like:

```
class TestModel(models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    reg_from = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True, default=0)
```

For some reason, while saving TestModel, I can't provide country information. I would like to update that later.

Krish

Comment: What does your Country model look like ie what values can it take?

Comment: It is looking for a country with primary key 0. You should rather have `country = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True, null=True)`

Comment: I don't have null value, because null value makes db slow. so every row where there is no country applicable, I would like to have 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made field null as quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's raising an error because there isn't an object in your Country models that has a `PK = 0`.

If you do not want to set your field to `null` then simply create a Country object with `pk=0` like: `Country.objects.create(name='No Country', pk=0)`.

Although, setting the field to `null` and having `default=0` might be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try None instead of 0. 0 is an integer, it should not work anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Change your definition to:

```
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True, null=True, default=0)
```

The `null=True` attribute will set NULL parameter on the `country` column in the DB, without that you should set a value for this column.

Also `default=0` is not necessary, because the default value will be null.

Comment: I don't have null value, because null value makes db slow. so every row where there is no country applicable, I would like to have 0

Comment: What? Null makes your DB slow? :-) OK, set `null=True` and `default=0`, then your database will set `country` to `0` by default.